# How to parse Javascript Date to Java LocalDateTime with day of the week

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to convert a Javascript Date that is stored in a mongoDb to a Java LocalDateTime ISO_DATE_TIME and I keep hitting a ParseException and I can not figure out why my code is slipping up. First off, the code:

Parser:

```
public static final class StringToLocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {

        public static final StringToLocalDateTimeConverter INSTANCE = new StringToLocalDateTimeConverter();

        private StringToLocalDateTimeConverter() {}

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
            return StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(source) ? null : LocalDateTime.parse(source, formatter);
        }
    }
```

The date that is being passed in is in the format of 'Thu Oct 07 2021 21:29:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'

The error I am receiving is:

*Exception in getUserById() with cause = 'java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Thu Oct 07 2021 21:29:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)' could not be parsed at index 0' and exception = 'Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDateTime] for value 'Thu Oct 07 2021 21:29:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'; nested exception is java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Thu Oct 07 2021 21:29:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)' could not be parsed at index 0'*

It seems that the parser does not know what to do with the leading day of the week. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Look at the pattern you're passing into `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`. It looks *nothing* like the value you're asking it to parse.

Comment: Apologies if I have it backwards, but I thought that was the output format I wanted to receive?

Comment: No. You're trying to parse to a `LocalDateTime`. That's just a value - it doesn't *have* a format. (If you want to convert it to a string other than in the default format, you need to specify the format at that point.) You're asking the `DateTimeFormatter` to be used to *parse* the incoming value, which means its pattern has to match the incoming value.

Comment: (If you can affect the format that is stored in MongoDB, I would do so - that's a horrible date/time format. But that's a different matter.)

Comment: Hmmm gotcha! I'll look into useing RFC_1123_DATE_TIME as the formatter instead. Looks like I had it all backwards in my mind.

Comment: And trust me, already making that push! All future updates to that DB will be in ISO_DATE_TIME format hopefully. Much thanks for the input!

Comment: Yes, use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for exchanging date-time values as text. That is why the standard was invented.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong date format pattern to parse your date string.

```
String parsePattern = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss O (zzzz)";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(parsePattern);


String dateString = "Wed Jan 26 2022 22:33:07 GMT+1 (Central European Standard Time)";
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime); // result 2022-01-26T22:33:07
```

Comment: Since RFC_1123_DATE_TIME didn't end up working as a proper formatter, I took a stab at yours and it definitely put me on the right track! Coupled with the answers from Jon Skeet, I ended up using


`String parsePattern = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx '('zzzz')'";`